# Purpose of Json schema file while loading data into Big query from a csv file

Tags: google-bigquery

Can someone please help me by stating the purpose of providing the json schema file while loading a file to BQtable using bq command. what are the advantages?

Dose this file help to maintain data integrity by avoiding any column swap ?

Regards,
Sreekanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying a JSON schema--instead of relying on auto-detect--means that you are ensured to get the expected types for each column being loaded. If you have data that looks like this, for example:

```
1,'foo',true
2,'bar',false
3,'baz',true
```

Schema auto-detection would infer that the type of the first column is an `INTEGER` (a.k.a. `INT64`). Maybe you plan to load more data in the future, though, that looks like this:

```
3.14,'foo',true
1.59,'bar',false
-2.001,'baz',true
```

In that case, you probably want the first column to have type `FLOAT` (a.k.a. `FLOAT64`) instead. If you provide a schema when you load the first file, you can specify a type of `FLOAT` for that column explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Elliott, Assuming that I have a BQ table with schema already created and i receive CSV data file daily once which i upload to GCS and then load it to BQ table, is it necessary to provide JSON schema structure while pushing data into this table daily?

Comment: You should not need to.